# Client-side filter of YUI Datatable with select list?

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

Can I filter the rows of a static dataset using multiple drop-down menus and a paginated YUI datatable ?

http://www.mappingbahia.org/project/iguape_dataset.html

Answer (score 1):

Each YAHOO.widget component such as [YUI DataTable](https://web.archive.org/web/20160728181128/https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) uses a [YUI DataSource](https://web.archive.org/web/20170110020107/https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datasource/) component which **provides data needed To populate each rendered YAHOO.widget component**. Bellow you can see how it works

[image: YUI datasource]

Notice each YAHOO.widget component **internally** makes a call To The underlying YUI datasource Through [sendRequest](https://web.archive.org/web/20160728101813/https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.DataSourceBase.html#method_sendRequest) method (See step 1). Now let's see sendRequest signature

```
sendRequest(request, callback)
```

- request

> **For remote data**, this request **may be a param/value string**, such as "id=123&name=foo". **For local data**, this request maybe a simpler value such as 123. Specifying parameters may be irrelevent, so this value **may be simply be null**

- callback

It is just **an JavaScript object** which can be described as follows (Notice each property)

```
var callback = {
    success:function(request, response, payload) {
        /*
         * successful request is performed by success property
         */
    },
    failure:function(request, response, payload) {
        /*
         * failure request is performed by failure property
         */
    },
    scope:null,
    argument:null
}
```

So when each YAHOO.widget component makes a call To The internally YUI datasource Through sendRequest method, It pass a **built-in callback object as shown above** which Takes care of rendering The YAHOO.widget component itself. So **if you want a custom behavior**, you need To make a call To The underlying YUI datasource and **pass your custom callback object To filter The data provided by The YUI datasource** as follows

```
var datatable = // YUI datatable settings goes here
```

To attach each **change** event To each select, you can use

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("sex", "change", function(e) {
    var value = e.getTarget(e).value;

    if(YAHOO.lang.isValue(value)) {
        /**
          * Notice i am retrieving The underlying datasource To make a call To sendRequest method
          */
        datatable.getDataSource().sendRequest(null, {
            success:function(request, response, payload) {
                /**
                  * because scope property (see bellow) refers To The datatable
                  * this keyword can be used To get a reference To The datatable
                  */

                /**
                  * initializeTable method clear any data stored by The datatable
                  */
                this.initializeTable();

                var rs = response.results;
                var filtered = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < rs.length; i++) {
                    /**
                      * Is The sex property equal To The value selected by The user ?
                      */ 
                    if(rs[i]["sex"] == value) {
                        filtered[filtered.length] = rs[i];
                    }
                }

                this.getRecordSet().setRecords(filtered, 0);

                // Update UI
                this.render();
            },
            scope:datatable,
            argument:null
        });
    }
});
```

Althoug not Tested, i am pretty sure it will work fine.

Comment: Hey, just found this and it was both incredibly helpful and annoyingly time-consuming. Thanks Arthur very much for putting the work into this answer. One minor thing needs to change for this code to work - that is, the paginator totalRecords property needs to be set. The initializeTable() method zeroes this property and if it is not set again the paginating will break. On the line immediately before this.render, include the following: `pag = this.get('paginator'); if (pag) {pag.set('totalRecords',filtered.length);}` EDIT: just to note, not whinging at you about the time-consuming, just at YUI2